# Join multiple columns in pandas dataframe separated by ';'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe of shape (3600963,10). I want to join the last 7 columns such that entries for each column are separated by ';'. This is what I do:

```
###List has column names to be joined. 
lst_col =['feature4','feature5','feature6','feature7','feature8','feature9','feature10'] 

new_df['info'] = new_df[lst_col].apply(lambda x: ';'.join(str(x)), axis = 1)
```

However, since my df is really big it is taking a very long to join these columns. Is there a way to do it faster? Insights will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Although a bit of a pain to write, I believe the below structure may produce faster results.

```
df['info'] = df['feature4'] + ';' + df['feature5'] + ';' + df['feature6']
```

Comment: Thank you Joe Rivera.Yes I did that as well and as you pointed out it is fast and it makes sense too. But I was wondering if there's a smart pythonic way to solve this problem rather than writing all these features.

Answer (score 0):

We can try `reduce` from `functools` to concatenate all the columns

```
from functools import reduce

df['info'] = reduce(lambda a, b: a + ';' + b, 
                   df[lst_col].astype(str).to_numpy().T)
```

Alternatively you can simply loop over the columns in the given column list and concatenate them with each other

```
df['info'] = ''
for col in lst_col:
    df['info'] += ';' + df[col].astype(str)
df['info'] =  df['info'].str[1:]
```